# How to set discount price for all products globally in opencart

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce, opencart

I need a discount price in all products in store to -5%. It has to show in product detail page and also product listing page like the individual discount price (strike-through). I want to apply the discount to all products in store globally. As i have tried, we have option to set discount price in the option tab while adding products but adding discount for each product seems to be long process. So i want to apply it globally. Any help or ideas will be greatly appreciated.

I checked some extensions but all show the global discount in the checkout page. I want to show it in the product details page based on the product price.

Comment: You can make a php page outside opencart that will change the discount into the database for all the product... this is only an initial idea.

Comment: You didn't check the extensions properly. I have done an extension that does exactly what You want... Search for *Mass discount* or by my nickname on OpenCart extensions store...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in product controller

```
$this->load->model('catalog/product');
$products = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts();
foreach ($products as $product) {
$this->model_catalog_product->setdiscount($product['product_id'],$product['price']);
}
```

in model

```
public function getProducts()
{
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT product_id, price FROM oc_product");
return $query->rows; 
}
    public function setdiscount($id,$price)
{

    $price=($price*95)/100;
    $query = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO oc_product_discount (product_id,customer_group_id,quantity,priority,price,date_start,date_end) VALUES ('".$id."','1','1','1','".$price."','xxx','yyy')");
}
```

xxx and yyy of your choice. and do change the customer_group_id,quantity,priority as per your req.

i have provided you the flow, do changes wherever you want.

Answer (score 3):

Open `catalog/model/catalog/product.php`

Find the line of code around line 40 that ends

```
=> $query->row['special'],
```

change it to

```
=> $query->row['price'] * 0.95,
```

And save. Note that if you have any discounts on the product, they will not appear with an additional 5% off the discount price. If you want that too, instead change the special line to end

```
($query->row['discount'] ? $query->row['discount'] : $query->row['price']) * 0.95,
```

Answer (score 0):

I have 18,000 products and needed to allow a discount to a particular customer group. I did NOT want to play with php!

I did it in mysql, operating on the opencart database. 0product_discount is the table you need to operate on. It will be empty until you create discount entries for a particular customer group against a product_id.

```
# open your opencart database in mysql
# first create a file listing the product_id's you want the discount applied to: you can restrict the 'select' as desired. 
# This selects all products. Or you can edit the file

select product_id into outfile '/home/junkfile' from 0product;
# outside mysql in a console run the following as a script file (this is for linux console should work in windows(???) idk
# read each product_id line from the file and creates an insert line with the proper data

while read line; do

echo "TRUNCATE TABLE 0product_discount;" >> testxx.sql
echo "" >> testxx.sql

# third item "3" is the customer_group_id
# quantity 1, priority 1 and price $1.0000
#OR you can use a percent discount
# dates are zeros for unlimited time frame

echo "INSERT INTO 0product_discount ( product_discount_id, product_id, customer_group_id, quantity, priority, price, date_start, date_end) VALUES ( '"${id}"','"${id}"', '3', '1', '1', '1.0000', '0000-00-00',  '0000-00-00');" >> testxx.sql

done < /home/junkfile

#This creates a form of mysqldump text file

## now use mysql -u [user] -p < testxx.sql to load the 0product_discount table
### note that the 'truncate line, clears out your failures ready for your next try!!
```

Not sure whether the discounted price will show up on the product page, but it does show up on checkout. Just add the customer to the proper group.