# How to set special price to products and options Globally in OPENCART 2.2

Tags: php, opencart, e-commerce, price

I need a special price to be applied in all products and options in store to -20%.  I want to apply the special price to all products and options in store globally. I have not found any plugin that supports special price including options.

I have checked some extensions but all show the global discount in the checkout page. I want to show it in the product details page based on the product price.

So i have to do it manually by editing catalogue/product and adding a global discount in both product price and options price. but i am not very sure how to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: The only plugin i found that does EXACTLY what i want is this:
https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=15727

But is does not support version 2.2. I have purchased it and figuring out how to make it work. If anyone could help me it would be great.

Comment: You can use this to accomplish what you described: https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=23507.  Disclosure: I am the developer of the linked extension.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set discount price for all products globally in opencart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992883/how-to-set-discount-price-for-all-products-globally-in-opencart)

Answer (score 0):

The plugins are available for that You can go through opencart.com marketplace and search as per your requirements.

The plugins such as All in one products block,Special pro etc.I 
think its fulfill your requirements.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your Answer but All in one products block does not support at all the feature i want. And the Special Pro well... i really cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: Ok. Thank You If i get solution i will inform you .